# Can't make the file_exists function work in PHP

Tags: php, file-exists

I'm facing a problem.

I have actually this code:

```
// Check if image exist for the hotel
$src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/007.jpg';

if(file_exists($src)) {
    $src = $src;
}
else {
    $src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/default.jpg';
}

echo '<center><img src="'.$src.'" width="200"></center>';
```

This code check for an image existence.

But each time I have the fallback image `default.jpg` whereas I should have `007.jpg`.

I check my path and it works. My `007.jpg` image is into the same directory as my `default.jpg` image.

I already test with `if(@getimagesize($src)) { ... }`. The same.

Why ?

Comment: Don't arbitrarily use the YOLO operator (`@`) which suppresses errors. Instead test the file exists first. Why does this do `$src=$src`? Check `if (!file_exists(...))`

Comment: Your `$src = $src;` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `$src = $src;` ... really?

Comment: @tadman I've never heard that deemed the "YOLO operator" until now, and I *love* it.

Comment: Try to use a absolute path, e.g. `__dir__ . '/../path/to/image.jpg`. Are you sure your are pointing to the right path ? `file_exists()` use local path, but image's src use "URL" path... not the same.

Comment: Do I need to use the same path for the check than for the display ?

Comment: What is the full exact path to the image?

Comment: Try renaming it, MI5 might be blocking it.

Comment: "The YOLO operator" ha ha ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it working by using:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

---

```
// Check if image exist for the hotel
$src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/007.jpg';

if(!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/app/images/hotel-logos/007.jpg')) {
    $src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/default.jpg';
}

echo '<center><img src="'.$src.'" width="200"></center>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Even that your file is placed at some directory, doesn't mean that the current path of the PHP process is the same. Use the absolute path instead:

```
// Check if image exist for the hotel
$src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/007.jpg';

if(!file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$src)) {
    $src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/default.jpg';
}

echo '<center><img src="'.$src.'" width="200"></center>';
```

Comment: I guess `__DIR__` will fail into `src` attribute.

Comment: Now, it's better :)

Comment: `$dir = __DIR__.'../assets/app/images'; echo '<center><img src="'.$dir.(file_exists("$dir/007.jpg") ? "/007" : "/default") .'.jpg" width="200"></center>';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over doing it make it simpler might solve your issue Try This:

```
<?php
$src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/007.jpg';

if (!file_exists($src)) {
    $src = '../assets/app/images/hotel-logos/default.jpg';
}
echo '<center><img src="'.$src.'" width="200"></center>';

?>
```